# Не получается разделить строки

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "black - чёрный, car - машина, blue - синий, apple - яблоко";
            string[] y = new string[4];
            y = x.Split(',');
;           string[] words = new string[y.Length * 2];
            for(int f = 0; f <= y.Length - 1; f++)
            {
                words = y[f].Split('-');
            }
            for(int j = 0; j <= words.Length -1; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(words[j]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Результат который хочу я:

```
words[0] = black
words[1] = чёрный 
words[2] = car
words[3] = машина
```

и так далее

А получается:

```
words[0] = apple
words[1] = яблоко
```

А другие не делятся, кроме последнего. В чем проблема? Программисты помогите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо

Comment: `var words = x.Split(",").SelectMany(s => s.Split("-")).ToList();`

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!